Can the WEBSERVICE function in Excel return anything malicious?
When using the WEBSERVICE function to return data from a website, what data type does it return? Can it return something like a macro? If a website originally has benign data, can it later be changed to be something malicious, which the function would then return without me knowing it was changed? Or can it only return non-executable data?
When I copy the WEBSERVICE function I want to use to another cell, a security notice pops up: "You're pasting active content. Active content, such as macros, can contain harmful code."
For context I am setting up a stock tracker in Excel and am worried about the security risks of using the function to return from a non-reputable website.

Are you asking for advice to ignore that warning?? Would you trust it more than that very clear message?

Excel is capable of performing unsafe actions, so yes, its very possible for a web-service to return data that will cause Excel to misbehave in dangerous ways. the data doesn't need to be executable, because excel does the processing.

"can it return something like a macro?" I'd think the warning message "Active content, such as macros, can contain harmful code" is a dead giveaway. So yes, it certainly can be risky.

Microsoft definitely has warnings about operating Active content (Such as macros, add-ins, or data connections.) or opening files containing Active content. The WEBSERVICE function returns data from a web service on the Internet or Intranet. Microsoft cannot theoretically guarantee the security of data sources, but it can warn you in advance.
